# Paging in Mule ESB

Tags: while-loop, mule, paging, esb

We have a Mule flow which processes a bunch of records. We want to implement paging because one of the steps in the process is calling an external system which can only take a set amount of records at a time.

We have attempted to solve this by adding a choice in the flow that checks if there are more records to process and if yes then call the same flow again (self reference the flow) but this caused stackoverflow errors.

We have also tried using the until-successful scope but we need errors to break out of the loop and be caught by the exception strategy.

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

Mule possesses the ability to process messages in batches
http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Batch+Processing

It is the best option for your requirement.